# Find key of first row containing a partial word match while searching a sentence

Tags: php, arrays, string, search, sub-array

Here is my issue:

```
$array = array(
    "1" => array("fruit", "salad", "vegetable"),
    "2" => array("beef", "meat", "sausage"),
    "3" => array("chocolate", "cake", "bread")
);

$sentence = "I love big sausage";
```

`$sentence` could also be `I love big sausageS`.

I need to associate a sentence to a category, so I need to analyze the sentence and to return the ID of the subarray matching with the sentence. For example "2" in my example.

I'm looking for the solution with the best performance. I guess I have no other choice than "explode" the sentence and "foreach" it at a minimum.

The project uses PHP7 and if it can use amazing native functions it'll be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best I can do.

Foreach the array and use preg_grep to find matches.
I use str_replace to replace spaces with | that is used as "or" in regex.

```
foreach($array as $key => $sub){
    if(preg_grep("/" . str_replace(" ", "|", $sentence) . "/" ,$sub )){
        echo "Match in ". $key . "\n";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/BqkW2

---

To match your sussageS example you can reverse the search and add `.*?` in the grep.

```
$arrSent = explode(" ", $sentence);
foreach($array as $key => $sub){
    if(preg_grep("/" . implode(".*?|", $sub) . ".*?/" , $arrSent))    
    {
        echo "Match in ". $key . "\n";
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/MJqrv

But this will also accept `sussage_and_beans`. If you only want to match if the word is in plural (an `s` added at the end). Change `.*?` to `s`.
But it will be case sensitive so sussageS as in your example will not work.
but with : `if(preg_grep("/" . implode("s|", $sub) . "s/i" , $arrSent))`
Should make it case insensitive.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot ! The second solution works really well and with just one loop ! Amazing.
The first solution seems to return any result which contains a part of a word in the sentence. For example if you have "bigmac" in the first array, the script will return you the ID 1 & 2 because of the "big" in the sentence.I thought it will be the opposite cause the second script looks more permissive than the first one. 
But anyway thanks a lot for what you did, you are awesome <3

Comment: But just a question : how to make the second script case insensitive ? Cause i tried to replace by your "if(preg_grep("/" . implode("s|", $sub) . "s/i" , $arrSent)" and it doesn't work, the script returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you explode your `$sentence` and use a whitespace as the delimiter you will get an array of words.

You could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove those arrays from `$array` by checking if the intersect contains 1 or more words using [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

Then you could return an array using [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get all the id's which contain word(s) that are in you sentence.

```
$array = array (
    "1" => array("fruit","salad","vegetable"),
    "2" => array("beef","meat","sausage"),
    "3" => array("chocolate","cake","bread")
);

$expl = explode(' ', "I love big sausage");
$array = array_filter($array, function($x) use ($expl) {
    return count(array_intersect($expl, $x)) > 0;
});
var_dump(array_keys($array));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/q54fA)

That would give you:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answers are making the mistake of trying to search the array of "needles" with the exploded or piped words in the "haystack". This will not work when you modify "sausage" in your sentence to "sausageS" -- there is no needle that has an `s` after `sausage`, so even if you use a case-insensitive approach it will still fail.

Because you are seeking a solitary qualifying key, it makes the most sense to stop searching as soon as a match is found.  This task requirement eliminates `array_filter()` and `preg_grep()` as best performers -- they will both keep scanning data until the input is exhausted instead of stopping as soon as a match is found.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/F6oJb))

```
$needlestack = [
    "1" => ["fruit", "salad", "vegetable"],
    "2" => ["beef", "meat", "sausage"],
    "3" => ["chocolate", "cake", "bread"]
];

// $haystack = "I love big sausage";
$haystack = "I love big sausageS";

$found = null;
foreach ($needlestack as $id => $needles) {
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            $found = $id;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
var_export($found); // 2
```

`stripos()` will perform case-insensitively AND will allow for partial word matching (which is desirable for matching `sausageS` to `sausage`).  By using nested loops and `stripos()`, this approach does not waste time preparing strings that will be unused.